# only 1 admob instance in all views

Tags: admob

Suppose my game has 3 scenes:

- MenuScene
- SelectLevelScene
- GameScene.

I use only 1 instance of admob in all scenes. If the click rate is high, does Google think I cheat? Does I need 3 instances of admob for that 3 scene?

Answer (score 0):

You should place your AdView on the Activity on which the user spends most of their time. Places that are transitory like menu or selection options are not a good site for advertising.

Admob (as all ad networks) employs click fraud detection algorithms. If you have abormal click rates then yes they might decide you are frauding the system.

Do you need 3 instances of Admob for the 3 scenes? It depends upon what you mean by scene and what you mean by Admob instances. You can definitely use the same AdUnitId in all 3 places.

Answer (score 0):

Im developing game in cocos2dx. Scene is something like activity in android. Suppose I have 3 scenes, does I need to "new Admob object" in each scene, or use only 1 Admob object (global)?